# Certificate verification with BIO_do_connect()

Tags: c++, openssl, ssl-certificate

Is certificate verification performed during a `BIO_do_connect` call?

I am trying to understand when to use `ssl_get_verify_result()`. 
The documentation says this function should be used in conjunction with `ssl_get_peer_certificate`. But some of the examples ([IBM's](https://developer.ibm.com/technologies/security/tutorials/l-openssl/) for instance) don't, saying that OpenSSL does the verification for us. They only call `ssl_get_verify_result()` after `BIO_do_connect`.

I see that `BIO_do_connect` is actually a macro:

```
/* BIO_s_accept() and BIO_s_connect() */
#  define BIO_do_connect(b)       BIO_do_handshake(b)
#  define BIO_do_accept(b)        BIO_do_handshake(b)
# endif /* OPENSSL_NO_SOCK */

# define BIO_do_handshake(b)     BIO_ctrl(b,BIO_C_DO_STATE_MACHINE,0,NULL)
```

So, my understanding is that `BIO_do_connect` does not actually check to see if the server sent a certificate. If the server does send a certificate, then `ssl_get_verify_result` will use that to perform verification. If it doesn't send one, then `ssl_get_verify_result` still returns `X509_V_OK`. That is why we need to call `ssl_get_peer_certificate` to make sure that a certificate is in fact sent. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [BIO_do_handshake](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/BIO_do_handshake.html) example, you are safe to call ssl_get_verify_result / ssl_get_peer_certificate after the call to BIO_do_handshake.

You can customize the verification process with [SSL_CTX_set_verify](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_CTX_set_verify.html) in which you can provide a callback verification function.  This allow you to provide your own validation rules like allowing overrides for things like self signed certificate support, etc.

Comment: A follow up: Through wireshark, I can see that `BIO_do_connect` will do both the TCP handshake and TLS handshake. Is there any particular reason why calling `BIO_do_handshake` is necessary? In fact, it doesn't actually have any effect when I do call it after `BIO_do_connect`.

Comment: You are looking at the implementation now...  Depends on if you want to be compatible between versions.  If you go by the documentation / samples, you should do BIO_do_connect / BIO_do_handshake.   If you don't care, BIO_do_connect will do (as you put in your question, they both to the same thing anyway) but it may break between versions, or updating to a different version or openssl.

Comment: I see. So just to be safe, I should be calling `BIO_do_handshake` anyway (even if it has no effect now), to ensure compatibility with future versions of openssl.