# Difference between `BIO_do_connect` and `BIO_do_handshake`

Tags: c++, openssl

Is there any functional difference between `BIO_do_connect` and `BIO_do_handshake`?

Both are defined as the same macro:

```
/* BIO_s_accept() and BIO_s_connect() */
#  define BIO_do_connect(b)       BIO_do_handshake(b)
#  define BIO_do_accept(b)        BIO_do_handshake(b)
# endif /* OPENSSL_NO_SOCK */

# define BIO_do_handshake(b)     BIO_ctrl(b,BIO_C_DO_STATE_MACHINE,0,NULL)
```

Most of the examples on writing a TLS client call `BIO_do_handshake` after `BIO_do_connect` to initiate an SSL handshake and open an SSL connection. But from what I have seen from analyzing network traffic using Wireshark, `BIO_do_connect` does both the TCP handshake and TLS handshake and opens an SSL connection.

Calling `BIO_do_handshake` afterwards has no effect.

Is there some state that the state machine transitions to after `BIO_do_connect` that necessitates calling `BIO_do_handshake`?

Is this some holdover from previous versions of OpenSSL and calling both `BIO_do_connect` and `BIO_do_handshake` is necessary to support backward compatibility?

These questions came up after I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60750323/2904614) on SE.